# Optimal Integration Pattern (bi-directional Sync) to use - Case and Incident Sync

Tags: integration, governorlimits, design-patterns

We are currently evaluating the **optimal integration pattern** (both Inbound and Outbound) to be used for our Service Cloud implementation. A simple use case is to **synchronize Cases and Incidents (bi-directional sync) via a middle tier**. Polling is out of scope.

The plan is to use **Request-Reply pattern for the inbound and Fire and Forget pattern for the outbound**. This perfectly aligns with the use case and business processes; however, *would like to understand the pros and cons of using a single pattern for both Inbound and Outbound calls, i.e either Request-Reply or Fire and Forget.*

From the analysis what we found are as below:

**Inbound Scenario**

For Inbound, **Request-Reply** works well as the *response is sent immediately as part of the same thread*. Ideally we do not feel any of the below governors are applicable here.

- Concurrent Apex Request Limit (10 requests over 5 seconds), no complex   business logic
- Concurrent API Request Limit (25 requests over 20 seconds), no complex logic and
- Total API Requests (not a big deal as it is a soft limit)

***What are the exact key limitations one should account for?***

For Inbound, **in case if Fire and Forget pattern is chosen**, we feel the below are the limitations.

Need to invoke a separate Outbound call (to pass the response) which eventually falls into the same inbound transaction. This along with auto retries might lead to the below governor:

- Concurrent Apex Request Limit

***Is our assumption justified? Are there any other limitations we should account for?***

**Outbound Scenario**

For Outbound, **Fire and Forget** works well as the process/thread need not wait until a response is sent back (the call to the target system goes via a middle tier).

However, in case if **Request-Replay** pattern is followed for **Outbound** the **thread/process has to wait until the response is received** or times out. After further analysis we found the below governors might be applicable for this case:

- Callout time-out Limit (10 seconds by default)
- Concurrent Apex Request Limit, ***Not sure if this comes into the
  act, does callout come under this governor? and what are the other  considerations?***